# Positive-definitive matrix: Confusion about "vector of zeros"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix):

> "In linear algebra, a symmetric $n \times n$ real matrix $M$ is said to be
>   positive definite if $z^TMz$ is positive for every non-zero column vector
>   $z$ of $n$ real numbers."

I have a matrix, shown here:

$D = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0.25 & 0.25\\ 0 & 0.25 & 0.25\end{pmatrix}$

Using the $x'Dx$ method, I came to the final solution of:

(Eq1) $x_1^2 + (0.25)x_2^2 + (.5)x_2x_3 + (0.25)x_3^2$

When testing (Eq1) = 0, I used the values of $x_1=0, x_2=-1, x_3=1$ (this resulted in (Eq1)=0 )

I declared this to be a **positive semidefinitive** matrix

---

The problem I am having is with the test. According to the definition, the z column vector should be "non-zero", yet I have used a zero-value in my test (with $x_1=0$).

According to the above information, should **every** value in the z column vector be a **non-zero** value? (or will the above situation where $x_1=0$, $x_2=-1$, $x_3=1$ ~~ which causes Eq1=0 and result in the $D$ matrix being positive semidefinitive be correct?)

Comment: Go back and read the definition. It doesn't say anything about the coordinates of $z$ being positive, but it does say that $z^TMz$ must be positive **for** ***every*** **nonzero column vector $z$**. Testing that $z^TMz>0$ for one nonzero value of $z$ is hardly sufficient to see that $z^TMz>0$ holds for all nonzero values of $z$. If you were trying to argue that all sheep are white, would "hey look, here's a white sheep" be sufficient justification for that claim?

Comment: To wckronholm: Thank you for editing my question. Is there a link to where I can use that kind of markup for future questions/answers?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula)

Comment: sea turtles: good point. So would finding a generalization be considered the better method in identifying that the matrix is indeed positive semi-definite?

Comment: What do you mean by "finding a generalization"?

Comment: For example, proving that the matrix = 0 whether or not any of the z-vector values are all non-zero. Like using x1=x3 (likely incorrect, but for explanation sake).

Comment: Still don't understand what you're trying to say. Perhaps you mean "finding nonzero vectors for which the $z^TMz$ equals zero"?

Comment: sea turtles: According to my textbook definition: if x'Ax >= 0 (and the equality holds for at least one vector-z != 0), then A is said to be positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

A vector $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is non-zero if at least one of the $x_i$'s is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

A "nonzero column vector" is a column vector that contains ANY nonzero entry. So your example is perfectly fine.

Indeed, the secret is that the zero-vector is all zeros, and a nonzero vector is anything that's not equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the polynomial can be written as $\displaystyle x_1^2+\left(\frac{x_2+x_3}{2}\right)^2$.

- Positive definite: can you make this polynomial equal $0$ without having all three coordinates equal zero at once? Think about what $A^2+B^2=0$ means for $A,B$ (in the reals).
- Positive semidefinite: can this polynomial ever be negative (again, in the reals)?